# Python unittest does not run tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I made a small project called demo, with a single test in it

```
import unittest


class Test(unittest.TestCase):


    def testName1(self):
        self.assertEqual(5+9, 14)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
    unittest.main()
```

However, from command line

```
ThinkPad-T520:~/workspacep/demo$ python -m unittest

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Why doesn't this work? In general, how can I run all unit tests from command line with a single line?

The structure of the directory is

```
demo
    tests
          demo_test1.py  __init__.py
```

Comment: Can you share directory structure of your project?

Comment: `python test_demo.py`

Comment: Well, for one thing, if you're executing `python -m unittest`, then inside your script, `__name__` is NOT equal to "main".

Comment: Please see edits of original question to see directory structure.

Comment: Also, John Gordon, what do you mean? You can see the code above, it is __main__.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fought with the same exact problem a while ago and I solved it by using test discovery command.

`python -m unittest discover -s .`

You can pass in your test file pattern as well and a whole other options https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery

Comment: Isn't the default using discover even without passing it explicitly in the command?

Comment: Btw, this failed for me as well, got the same result as above, Ran 0 tests

Comment: @BaronYugovich It probably failed because the default pattern to match test files is `test*.py` while the test file name `demo_test1.py` can only be matched by `"*_test*.py"`

Try `python -m unittest discover -s . -p "*test*.py"`

Answer (score 28):

There are three gotcha's that I know of:

1. Your tests in your TestCases need to be named `test_*`
2. Your test files need to be named: `test*.py` (by default, you can change it with the `-p` flag when running the tests). e.g. `test_demo1.py`
3. Your `tests` folder needs to have an `__init__.py` file in it, or else it won't be considered a valid location to import from.

So, for #1, you need to rename the test to `test_name_1`. And for #2, there's two options:

**A** - Restructure your files like this:

```
demo
    tests
        __init__.py
        test_demo1.py
```

Then run `python -m unittest` and it should find the test cases.

**B** - Just run it like: `python -m unittest discover -p *test.py`

Comment: That the test cases' names need to begin with `test_` is correct, but names of my test files actually needed to begin with `test_` as well. The file `__init__.py` was not required (I'm doodling around with the `unittest` module and just have a single directory). When respecting these rules, the command `python -m unittest` worked with or without any `discover` options. Maybe those are recent changes, I'm on python 3.8.11.

Comment: The official documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest-test-discovery) states that the pattern is `test*.py`, not `test_*.py` for file names (I manually checked this, too). I see no discrepancy with my answer for the rest of your comment: this situation is for test files inside a folder (needing `__init__.py`) and using defaults (so, don't need add `discover` to the command)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in a [list of modules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface).

For example, if your test file is `foo.py`, then you can run `python -m unittest foo`.

Comment: No, that's what I want to avoid. I want it to run all tests in a project. Assume this is a huge project with 100s of modules, I don't want to pass them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

For me (running tests from [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)) I had to remove the class' *'Run configuration'*. Earlier on I had wrongly imported the unittest as _pytest.unittest and ran the test class. Of course that didn't work.

I corrected the module import, but the 'run configuration' was still there, causing it to run as a Python script and not as 'Python tests'.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and figured out that I had to run `python3 -m unittest` instead as I had forgotten `python` defaults to Python 2 on my system